# Using jQuery to trigger Enter event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image tag :

```
         <img src='Presale.png' alt='presell' onclick="presell()"/> Presell
```

Function :

```
function presell()
{
    $(".form-control").val("presell");
    var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
    e.which = 13;
    e.keyCode = 13;
    $(".form-control").trigger(e);
}
```

What I wanted to do was to fill a search box with some text and trigger `enter` the moment a particular image is clicked so that search related to that image is made. But this code is putting the value to the search box but not triggering `enter`.

Comment: You may not need to trigger enter. Instead -- assuming your search bar is in a form -- you can trigger `"submit"` on the form (the same effect as pressing enter while the field is selected).

Comment: By triggering enter, you want the form to submit? (In that case you could call $(".form-control").submit() instead

Comment: do you have a full form `<form></form>` or just the input?

Comment: What is the reason for needing to trigger enter? Can you not just call a function when the image is clicked?

Comment: If this is an acceptable solution to you, I can write up an example.

Comment: I dont have a form. Thats the problem. Its just an input box which filters the content of a tabel using some js code which i dont know. I just know that if something is entered in it and enter is pressed then the search results are shown.

Answer (score 1):

You need to submit the actual form, instead of triggering a `keypress` event with `enter`'s keycode (does not work)

e.g.

```
$("form").submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
<img src='Presale.png' alt='presell' /> Presell
<form>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
</form>
```

Note: I removed the click handler from the image.

And in the JS:

```
$("img").on("click", function(){
    $(".form-control").val("presell");
    $("form").submit();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/v7havjov/)

Comment: Its not a form. Just an input field.

Comment: Can you post a link to somewhere it can be seen? Not sure about hitting enter, but there could be some other event bound to the input field which you would need to trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you need is to simulate a 'return/enter' key press which would most naturally submit the value of the input (which can be via submit/AJAX)

`.trigger()` would call the eventhandler and not simulate the native browser event. Refer: http://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/

You would then need to bind an event handler to the enter keypress and provide what is to be done anyway. Which means including `.submit()` or `post()` or `$.ajax()` or whatever code that is called (unless it is defined on a trigger handler)

What you probably need is `.simulate();` available via **jquery.simulate.js**